# Scipy.linalg.logm produces an error where matlab does not

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

The line `scipy.linalg.logm(np.diag([-1.j, 1.j]))` produces an error with scipy 0.17.1, while the same call to matlab, `logm(diag([-i, i]))`, produces valid output. I already filed a [bugreport on github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6378), now I am here to ask for a workaround. Is there any implementation of logm in Python, that can do `logm(np.diag([-1.j, 1.j]))`?

EDIT: The error is fixed in scipy 0.18.0rc2, so this thread is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough about the calculation to understand the error.  But it has something to do division by zero - probably in the real part.

Replacing the zero real part of the array with a small value works:

```
In [40]: linalg.logm(np.diag([1e-16-1.j,1e-16+1.j]))
Out[40]: 
array([[  5.00000000e-33-1.57079633j,   0.00000000e+00+0.j        ],
       [  0.00000000e+00+0.j        ,   5.00000000e-33+1.57079633j]])
```

So the small real part could be removed with

```
In [47]: linalg.logm(np.diag([1e-16-1.j,1e-16+1.j])).imag*1j
Out[47]: 
array([[-0.-1.57079633j,  0.+0.j        ],
       [ 0.+0.j        ,  0.+1.57079633j]])
```

Comment: Thank you. As stated in my edit, the error is fixed in the new scipy release candidate, but your workaround is fine.